# How would you describe poor/bad family relations?

Tags: word-choice

i.e Sam had a _____________ relationship with his family, with the omitted space being an adjective showing the toxic/bad relations between Sam and his family.

'Strained' comes to mind, but some others would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Poor* itself would be a great option. With apologies to Charles Lamb.

Comment: @Kate Bunting True, but it's also used in "estranged relationships with someone" kind of expressions.

Comment: I suggest a thesaurus

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's wrong with *toxic*, *bad*, and *strained*? If there is some specific quality you're looking for you should describe that; if you just want a lot of possibilities, this is not a good place to ask (Thesaurus.com is an easy online resource, and Merriam-Webster's synonyms section of definitions is also often very helpful).

Answer (score 2):

A [fraught](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fraught) relationship (MW)

> causing or characterized by emotional distress or tension : uneasy; "a fraught relationship"

Comment: +1 "Eighteen months ago, she began writing about her childhood and her fraught relationship with her mother." (ODO) https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fraught

Answer (score 2):

The word **dysfunctional** is often used to describe personal relationships which are unhealthy or toxic. It's so common, the term [dysfunctional family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysfunctional_family) has its own Wikipedia page. Relationships can be dysfunctional in many ways, some of the more common being lack of empathy or boundaries, a power imbalance, or constant conflict or arguing.

Answer (score 0):

a **pernicious** relationship [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/pernicious)

> adj exceedingly harmful

Answer (score 0):

I might be inclined to use ***difficult***.  Per the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[difficult](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/difficult)***
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1  Needing much effort or skill to accomplish, deal with, or understand.
>
> *‘she had a difficult decision to make’*
> *‘the questions are too difficult for the children’*
>
> 1.1 Characterized by or causing hardships or problems.
>
> *‘a difficult economic climate’*
>
> 1.2 (of a person) not easy to please or satisfy; awkward.
>
> *‘Lily could be difficult’*

There are many [synonyms of *difficult*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/difficult) that could be used as well.